# importing values from flat file excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Hi I have to import values into an excel file as in the following way:

Values have to be imported based on last 8 characters in each line i.e. 00004100.
Assume 00004 is column5 and 100 is column6.

I need to import values into separate excel sheet for every unique pair of column5 and column6. i.e. all rows with last 8 digit as 00002100 will go in one excel sheet and so on.

```
1234 john smith  america 00002100
1234 john smith  america 00002100
1234 john smith  america 00002200
1234 john smith  america 00002200
1234 john smith  america 00003100
1234 john smith  america 00003200
1234 john smith  america 00003200
1234 john smith  america 00004100
1234 john smith  america 00002100
```

How to generate excel sheets based on the given criteria in vb!?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want to use VBA-Excel or VB.Net? They both are different...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is a VB question? Do you use Interop?
Since I do not know this, I am using pseudocode - but I think you will get the idea.
Its more like vb.net - if you use vba, the general Idea will work.

Generally i would to the following: Iterate over each row and concenate an new string.
Like this:

```
For row = 0 to rows.count-1
dim str as new stringbuilder()


 for col = 0 to rows(row).count-1
    str.append(rows(row).item(col)
 next

dim lasteight=str.tostring
lasteight=lasteight.substring(lasteight.length-8)

'here do the following: have a list of your sheetnames. If this list contains lasteight goto this page and append the row. if no sheet exist, create one and append as well.
next
```

Comment: thnx! Ishall look into this...
I am using an excel template which would be copied every time a new list of values is created. And thn using open xml to populate values for each report to be generated and othr data to be incorporated.